# Pdo wrapper function is safe?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a PDO wrapper that have `select, insert, delete, update` function, actually I made the update functon that look's like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $table name of the table
 * @param array $data data to update
 * @param string $where where clause
 * @return bool result
 */
public function update($table, $data, $where)
{
    ksort($data);

    $fieldDetails = NULL;
    foreach($data as $key=> $value)
    {
        $fieldDetails .= "`$key`=:$key,";
    }
    $fieldDetails = rtrim($fieldDetails, ',');

    $sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    return $sth->execute();
}
```

an example of usage:

```
$postData = array(
        'username' => 'foo',
        'role' =>'admin'
    );

$this->db->update('login', $postData, "`id` = {$data['id']}");
```

I don't know if this is secure or I missed something important, someone have suggestione to improve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on where the values in `$data` come from. If they're from user input, then you can get SQL injection. It would be better if that were an array like `$postData`, and you used `bindValue` for that as well.

Comment: @Barmar yes come from user input..

Comment: Then you should use `bindValue`, or at least use `$this->escape()`

Comment: on the where? 'cause I already bind the value of data inside the function

Comment: You're only using bound values in `$fieldDetails`, not `$where`.

Comment: so if a bind the value of where like fieldDetails this can be considered safe?

Comment: Yes. I assume you already validate the keys, since they can't be protected as bound variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it is not safe, for two reasons.

- First, `$data['id']` is put directly to the query and thus is not safe. It have to be bound as well.
- Second, `$key` is put directly to the query and thus is not safe. I wrote an article that demonstrates such a vulnerability and offers a solution: [An SQL injection against which prepared statements won't help](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)
- Third, `$table` is put directly to the query and thus is not safe. I know it is *meant* to be hardcoded in the function call, but you asked here whether this function is safe, while we cannot know how you're calling it.
  Besides, as the project grows, it's gets hard to keep the manual control on the data flow. So eventually a table name would become a variable and some day may be accepted from user input. Therefore, it's better to make your function impenetrable by itself, irrelevant to whatever external matters. Just like prepared statements do.

To fix the two latter vulnerabilities you should whitelist your keys, or, at the very least, format them properly. And **it should be done in this very function**. Otherwise by no means you can call it safe.

Comment: Thanks I'll adjust which your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I stumble on your question coming from https://laurent22.github.io/so-injections/ which is a statistics of the php related questions on SO with SQL Injection vulnerabilities in them.

So, no. This is not secure as it is now.

This is what is reported as vulnerable and I am quoting it here for future references.

```
$sth = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fieldDetails WHERE $where");
```

Without a doubt, this is used in a lot of code, in a lot of software. Hopefully this will be useful to others too.